# Are there any graduate programs similar to Georgia Tech's?

Tags: hardware, software

While I remain interested in sound design, I am also interested in audio hardware/software engineering. The only program that really covers what I'm looking at is at Georgia Tech. However, I'm only a college freshman, and programs can change or disappear in three years. Does anyone know of any other similar Master's programs? Thanks.

Comment: @Mercy - the acoustics and dynamics program has been around for years, as has all of the EE programs that deal with DSP.  While I don't know much about the Music Technology degree, you're a safe bet on those programs.  Put your calculus hat on!

Answer (score 1):

I know [CalArts](http://mtiid.calarts.edu/) has a Music Technology Program. It's pretty in depth as well. However, It seems you want something even more technical than what they are offering (even though what they do is very intensive and experimental). They focus on programming and instrument design more in the context of performance and art than to say become a hardware designer for a company like Korg or to Design DSP algorithms and micro chips for Analog Devices.

Check out the "[Links](http://mtiid.calarts.edu/links)" section of the CalArts site as well. Of note would be the Music Technology Institutions section. In there I'm sure you can find just the exact type of info you're looking for considering they're listing institutions like the Georgia Tech, Princeton Sound Lab, Columbia, UC Berkley, MIT Media Lab and IRCAM.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the programs at Carnegie Mellon. They used to have programs along those lines (actual scientific engineering as it relates to audio) years ago...maybe they still do.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about this one myself.  I've heard rumours of one in either Blackpool or Manchester in the UK, though I haven't actually sat down and looked.  Might be cool though, finding a school in Europe somewhere and geeking out on audio.